# Stripe subscription plan with trial but immediate payment and with end date

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using `Stripe` payment gateway. I am working on a project having `recurring` payments.

Basically I have `three plans` created on `Stripe`,

```
1) Free  - 14 days, $0.00 , No trial, Should NOT be auto renewed
2) Basic - 1 Month, $15.00, No trial, auto renewed 
3) Pro   - 1 Month, $25.00, No trial, auto renewed
```

I have some doubts as following:

1) Is it required to provide the credit card details while subscribing a customer to a `Free` plan? What if I don't want to provide it for now and still subscribe him to `Free` plan?

2) I don't want the `Free` plan to be auto-renewed. So `subscribing` any customer to `Free` plan, how can I identify the end of the period or cycle using webhook since there is NO end date/period is there for plan? I want to `cancel` the customers' `subscription` (having `Free` plan) `after 14 days` and redirect them to choose `Basic` or `Pro` plan with `credit card details`.

3) For `Basic` and `Pro` plans there is `no trial` period has set. But still I want to provide `14 days trial` to some specific customers. Is it possible by setting `trial_end` while `subscribing` a `customer` to a `plan` (i.e. For `Basic` or `Pro`)?

4) If I specify the `trial_end` attribute while `subscribing` a `customer` to a `plan` (i.e. `Basic` or `Pro`), the `charge` will be `created after the trial period ends`. Correct me? If yes, **what if I want to charge them immediate but still they must have the trial period?**

Answer (score 3):

1) No, it's not. Credit card information is not required. So, you can subscribe without credit card data. Credit card information is stored in `source`, and it's optional. I have tried it. [Create a subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription)

2) The subscription is always auto renew. If you don't want the subscription to be auto renew, you can subsribe without credit card. So, when the system tried to renew and failed, it will be as `canceled` or `unpaid`.  See [The subscription object](https://stripe.com/docs/api#subscription_object) in status attribute.

3) Yes, it is possible. You can set / update the trial_end.

4) Yes. But I think, you can not to charge them immediate with still they must have the trial period.

**My question:** Why you have 3 plans with no trial at all?

**My suggestion** is, you should have 3 plans, and for the `Free` plan, it should has trial 14 days. So when user choose `Free` plan, it will have 14 days trial, and without credit card. Then when trial period is up, and it will auto renew and payment to renew the subscription will fails (because of no credit card). So then user should change plan to `Basic` or `Pro` with the credit card data. And for these plans, it should charge them immediately, without trial (trial_end = now).

*Without a credit card, the subscription charge attempt will fail after that trial, and the subscription will be marked as delinquent. You may consider that to be useful*

For more information about Stripe Trial, you can follow this link [Using Trial Periods on Subscriptions](https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/trials)

Answer (score 0):

1) I would handle this in your program itself. (without connecting to stripe)  Let them sign up via your website without credit card details and then when the 14 days are up expire there membership so when they login next it prompts them to choose a plan.

2) If you handle this as I suggested in number 1 the users membership would expire and would not renew.

3) Yes the credit card info would be taken, but would not be charged until after the trial period.

4) You can give the customer an option to accept the trial period or not, but I am sure most users would prefer to have it because its like getting 14 days free.

Docs:
[Stripe Subscriptions](https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions), [Webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks), [Event Types](https://stripe.com/docs/api/python#event_types)

Comment: What if I create a free plan (with $0.00 and 14 days long) and subscribe user to it? What notification (webhook event) will I get at auto-renewal? As I am providing some public page services, I would require to expire the login automatically. In 1) case, if user does not login after 13 days then the account will not be expired. I don't want to handle this using cron-job.

Comment: In your model I would create an expire field and then set that when the free plan is created (set it for 14 days from day of sign up).  And run a check at login if their account is active or not and handle the case there.  You wouldn't need a cron job for this.  Then if they upgrade change the expire field to the appropriate value.  Personally, I only use stripe for payments and subscriptions I leave most of the logic in my programs.  What language are you using for this?  (ruby, python) When the free trial ends there will be a 'customer.subscription.updated'

Comment: When a subscription is created you will receive a 'customer.subscription.created' event and when the free trial ends there will be a 'customer.subscription.updated'.  An hour or so after that there would be a 'invoice.payment_succeeded' or 'invoice.payment_failed'.

Comment: I realize this is late, but for anyone's future needs, there is also a `customer.subscription.trial_will_end` that gets triggered when a trial will end so you could set a webhook up that listens for that event.